# When did the cost of living differences between Switzerland and neighboring countries became noticeable?

Tags: europe, money, finance, switzerland

Today it is widely known that prices of general goods in Switzerland are somewhat double those of Europe (rough generalization). There are a number of factors that contribute to this, notably the strength of [CHF](https://studyinginswitzerland.com/swiss-franc-facts/), prosperity, high wages, etc.

I’d like to know **when** exactly these differences began to appear. I’m specially interested in not-so-important regions on the borders. For instance, a coffee and a croissant will cost about 8.- CHF in Lugano, however, just a few kilometers to the south in Como, one could probably buy the same for 3.5 CHF (around 3.3 euros). I imagine that in the 1600s the difference in price between a loaf of bread in Chiasso and Como was negligible.

When in time did the prices started to become noticeably different?

Comment: Higher prices are usually linked to higher wages. Find out when Swiss wages began to differ from its neighbours. (Probably after WW2.)

Comment: It was certainly like that in the 60s, when I used to go to there. Though when I was there five years ago the difference had become noticeably more marked. During 3 or 4 days I was able to count literally on the fingers of one hand the number of cars I saw with EU countries' reg plates. It seems that Switzerland is widely boycotted by EU citizens, simply on the grounds of cost. Drinks especially are so expensive in restaurants that  at one establishment we asked for water. And they charged 4.50 SwFr for a caraffe of water. (i.e. roughly Euro 4.36). We couldn't get away to Italy fast enough.

Comment: @WS2: There's a world of difference between "boycot" and "not having a reason to go there"...

Comment: I went there when it was still francs , and a swiss franc was worth two french francs - late 70s? The price labels were the same... things that cost 4 french francs cost 4 swiss francs, so double.

Comment: @DevSolar Bear in mind that this was Zermatt - surely one of the world's most beautiful areas at the foot of the Matterhorn. The Swiss Alps are truly breathtaking. It was mid-summer and it seemed astonishing that there were so few German, French or Italian cars around. (Maybe more go for the snow in winter, but I believe many people are put off Switzerland by the cost).

Comment: @Jos I have been trying to see the point of your comment but it's impossible for me. It is in my eyes the equivalent of answering "When did WW2 start?" with "War is associated with conflict. Find out when conflict began in Europe". If I had access to the information you suggest, this question would not have been posted here...

Comment: I don't know a lot about statistics or economics. Just tried to give you a point of access.

Comment: A quick look at the data for [Switzerland](https://tradingeconomics.com/switzerland/consumer-price-index-cpi) versus [Italy](https://tradingeconomics.com/italy/consumer-price-index-cpi) does seem to show it's been this way for decades.

Comment: It’s dubious if in 1600s—lacking a generalised wage labour and capital society that goods were “priced”—that Swiss and Italian “prices” can be meaningfully compared. I view this as a question on *class consciousness* of geographic and political wage and price differentials.  Those who came from a regional city to a capital city in imperialism know the rent wage price variance and in the wage access to employment

Comment: So FSO (2021) je-e-03.04.03.02.01 https://www.bfs.admin.ch/bfs/en/home/statistics/work-income/wages-income-employment-labour-costs.assetdetail.16904718.html covers 1939 to 2021 in Switzerland (1939-2009 implicit).  From 1939 to 2021 real wages increased from 100 units to 300 units.  While this is a common statistical fairytale given by governments influencing their statistical units; in the case of Switzerland I suspect that high prices (including rents) indicate a high nominal wage structure.  If a croissant costs 1/40000th of a year's wage in Ch and It it costs the same.

Comment: (Of course, you may prefer to shovel [excrement] in Italy to shovelling [excrement] in Switzerland; and, to that, I'd give Marx and the Marginalists answer regarding specific utility preferences in political economy: use-value (Marx) or effective preference (marginal utility) reflects not the desire to eat a croissant but rather the desire to *purchase* a thing claimed to be a croissant.  As discovered by the utilitarians, my enjoyment of a croissant (or Italian refuse) and your enjoyment of a croissant (or Swiss refuse) are incommensurable.  For more on incommensurability see Derrida on words